# Finding highly deviated numbers in a number set

Tags: java, math, statistics

I have a number set and there is a standard value and other numbers should have a close values to it. But there are some numbers which are highly deviated from that number and I want to find them. I would like to know whether there are any statistical distribution can be used to solve this problem. Also I am implementing this using Java and would like to know whether there are any libraries I can use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Statistical library for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448643/statistical-library-for-java)

Answer (score 2):

The [Apache Math library](http://commons.apache.org/math/) has the functionality you're looking for.  Choose which distribution your population should be following, and you're set.